# For some reason my code isn't advancing when its reading the file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Basically I am trying to get the program to read the file and take the values to draw some simple shapes. The code is not advancing and it is assigning the shape as the first line and wont do anything else.

Here is the file I am trying to read:

```
SQUARE
r
b
200#200
40
RECTANGLE
b
g
100#100
10
SQUARE
r
b
500#355
40
SQUARE
g
b
600#60
15
END
```

I have tried moving the readline() around the place, but it doesn't seem to fix the problem, like before the whileloop and all that.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640,640))
R = (255,0,0)
B = (0,0,255)
G = (0,255,0)
shapefile = open("read_file.txt","r")
donereadingfile = True

line = shapefile.readline()
while donereadingfile:
   if (line == "END\n") or (line == "END"):
       donereadingfile = False

   elif(line == "RECTANGLE\n"):
       RECTANGLE = line
       RECTANGLE = RECTANGLE.rstrip("\n")

       line = shapefile.readline()
       circle_colour = line
       circle_colour = circle_colour.rstrip("\n")
       if circle_colour == ("r"):
           circle_colour = R
       elif circle_colour == ("b"):
           circle_colour = B
       elif circle_colour == ("g"):
           circle_colour = G

       line = shapefile.readline()
       border_colour = line
       border_colour = border_colour.rstrip("\n")

       if border_colour == ("r"):
           border_colour = R
       elif border_colour == ("b"):
           border_colour = B
       elif border_colour == ("g"):
           border_colour = G

       line = shapefile.readline()
       coordinate = line
       coordinate = coordinate.rstrip("\n")
       coordinate = coordinate.split("#")
       x = int(coordinate[0])
       y= int(coordinate[1])


       line = shapefile.readline()
       diameter = line
       diameter = diameter.rstrip("\n")
       diameter = int(diameter)

       pygame.draw.rect(screen,border_colour,(int(x),int(y),3*diameter,diameter),3)
       pygame.draw.circle(screen,circle_colour,x,y,(diameter/2))
       pygame.display.update()

   elif (line == "SQUARE\n"):
       SQUARE = line
       SQUARE = SQUARE.rstrip("\n")

       line = shapefile.readline()
       circle_colour = line
       circle_colour = circle_colour.rstrip("\n")
       if circle_colour == ("r"):
           circle_colour = R
       elif circle_colour == ("b"):
           circle_colour = B
       elif circle_colour == ("g"):
           circle_colour = G

       line = shapefile.readline()
       border_colour = line
       border_colour = border_colour.rstrip("\n")

       if border_colour == ("r"):
           border_colour = R
       elif border_colour == ("b"):
           border_colour = B
       elif border_colour == ("g"):
           border_colour = G

       line = shapefile.readline()
       coordinate = line
       coordinate = coordinate.rstrip("\n")
       coordinate = coordinate.split("#")
       x = int(coordinate[0])
       y= int(coordinate[1])



       line = shapefile.readline()
       diameter = line
       diameter = diameter.rstrip("\n")
       diameter = int(diameter)

       pygame.draw.rect(screen,border_colour,(x,y,diameter,diameter),3)
       pygame.draw.circle(screen,(circle_colour,x,y,(diameter/2))
       pygame.display.update()

shapefile.close()
```

it says "    x = int(coordinate[0])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'SQUARE'

I dont understand why but it should print out the shapes that is suppose to.

Comment: Why are you doing this: `coordinate = line`? You're reading a line into `coordinate` and then replacing it with `line` again? That is the reason coordinate has the value "SQUARE" in it instead of the coordinates you expect

Comment: @razdi I fixed that in the new edit

Comment: That still looks wrong to me. Shouldn't it be `coordinate = line` ?

Comment: Also, the drive link you've pasted does not give us access. Please add a sample of the data to the question itself instead of the link

Comment: @razdi I opened the google drive again so try the link now. Let me know if it does not work

Comment: Does the error still continue after you switched coordinate and line as per the previous comment?

Comment: I tried the code out apart from the `pygame.draw()` stuff and it seems to be working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use a for loop instead:

```
with open( 'file', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line)
```

That way you don't have to use a stop condition, and it is easier to debug.